# Postgres is it necessary to include two predicates in this where clause?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a query which returns all rows where `action1` is not `'t'` (including instances where `action1` is `null`)

This query does not return the `null` records:

```
select * 
from actions 
where action1 <> 't'
```

This query does return the `null` records, but I'm surprised both predicates are necessary

```
select *
from event_actions
where action_c2 is null or action_c2 <> 't'
```

Is there a way to write this query without both predicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IS DISTINCT FROM` construction in the comparison, which treats `null` as if it is a known value that is different from any non-null value i.e.

```
select * 
from actions 
where action1 is distinct from 't'
```

`a is distinct from b` is equivalent to

```
case 
 when a is null then b is null 
 else a is not null then b is not null and a = b 
end
```

For reference: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from